# Angular Material Table - CSS to get headers to left align when text wraps

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, angular-material

With the [Angular Material Table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) component, by default, the column headers on a table will left align, which is great:

[image: Left aligned headers]

However, if there isn't enough room for the header then the text wraps, which is fine except that the text then center aligns...

[image: Center align text]

How do I make the text left align? I thought this would be straight forward, but I'm having issues. This also only appears to happen on headers with sorting, because if you remove the `mat-sort-header` directive from any of the header cells, things left align correctly.

I tried adding the following css class definition, but no luck:

```
.mat-sort-header-button {
    text-align: left;
}
```

[Here is the demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhq2cv?file=app%2Ftable-sorting-example.css) I'm playing around with.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhq2cv-8rtpvp?file=app/table-sorting-example.css

Comment: Awesome, thank you! If you put that as an answer I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why your styles is not working is that Angular uses Emulated encapsulation be default so your styles are component scoped. That means that you can only apply class to element which is placed in component template directly. You can't style nested components.

[image]

To style elements from nested components you have to use ::ng-deep selector:

```
::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-button {
  text-align: left;
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhq2cv-8rtpvp?file=app/table-sorting-example.css)**

There are other ways to solve it:

- using `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`
- using global styles

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for global styling, then check this.

[StackBlitz link for sort header alignment](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhq2cv-hvrkxy?file=styles.css)

Define below styles in style.css:

**For text alignment in sort header or normal header**

```
th.text-align-left,th.text-align-left .mat-sort-header-button {
    text-align: left !important;
}
th.text-align-right,th.text-align-right .mat-sort-header-button {
    text-align: right !important;
}
th.text-align-center,th.text-align-center .mat-sort-header-button {
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

**For Content Alignment in sort header**

```
th.align-center .mat-sort-header-container {
    justify-content: center;
}
th.align-right .mat-sort-header-container {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
th.align-left .mat-sort-header-container {
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

And you can use these text-align-left, align-left etc classes in th